# How can i optimize my schema to remove useless default index on "_id"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

This is my document structure :

```
db.like
{
  _id: objectid, /* not null */ 
  id_from: int64, /* not null */
  id_to: int64, /* not null */
  date: datetime, /* default NOW not null */
}

db.like.createIndex( {"id_to": 1, "id_from": 1}, {unique: true} );  
db.like.createIndex( {"id_to": 1, "date": -1}, {unique: false} );
```

I load document **only in one of these ways:**

```
db.like.find({$and: [{id_to:xxx}, {id_from:yyyy}]})
```

or

```
db.like.find({id_to:xxx}).sort({date:-1});
```

and later i shard the collection like this :

```
sh.shardCollection( "like", {"id_to": 1, "id_from": 1}, unique: true );
```

As you see i don't use at all the index on `"_id"`. I m a little worry to have an index on `"_id"` that seam to be **useless**. Is their a way to optimize my schema or better to leave it like this ?

---

NOTE: the solution must work with **sharding**, so the solution given by clcto seam to be bad for this! it's solution was to declare _id as a document like :

```
{
   _id : { 
      to : int64,
      from : int64
   },
   date : datetime
}
```

but i m quite sure that with such declaration query like

```
db.like.find({id_to:xxx}).sort({date:-1});
```

will be done on all shards

Comment: Mongo is designed so that each document needs to have a unique id, which is ensured by the unique index on `_id`. AFAIK, you cannot remove it, but you can set up your document so that `_id` is a document containing `id_to` and `id_from`, since from the code provided is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @clcto : thank but how you will setup _id to be a document containing id_to and id_from and at the same time keep my 2 queries performants ?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo is designed so that each document needs to have a unique id, which is ensured by the unique index on `_id`. AFAIK, you cannot remove it, but if you are able to change the schema, you can set up your document so that `_id` is a document containing `id_to` and `id_from`, since from the code provided is guaranteed to be unique:

```
{
   _id : { 
      to : int64,
      from : int64
   },
   date : datetime
}
```

For the indexes, since the id index is already created, so you don't need that one. You can index into the `_id` document for the second:

```
db.like.createIndex( {"_id.to": 1, "date": -1}, {unique: false} );
```

Then your queries would be:

```
db.like.find({ _id : { to: xxx, from: yyyy } });
db.like.find({ _id.to: xxx }).sort({date:-1});
```

**Note:** MongoDB requires the `_id` to be immutable, so if you need to be able to update the original fields `id_to` and `id_from`, you cannot use this method.

Comment: hmm interesting, and what about the sharding ? i will shard on sh.shardCollection( "like", {"_id.to": 1, "_id.from": 1}, unique: true ); ? or simply on sh.shardCollection( "like", {"_id": 1}, unique: true );

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongo sharding so I cannot answer that.

Comment: is their any doc somewhere about using document as _id ? is their any drawback of such method ?

Comment: The only drawback I know about is that the `_id` field is immutable. So if these fields need to be updated later, this method cannot be used.

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html: *"Documents have the following restrictions on field names:

    The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array."*

Comment: thanks! but now that i look i m quite sure (if not completely sure) that the sharding will not work :( to shard i need an index so if i shard on "_id" then i m sure that doing db.like.find({ _id.to: xxx }).sort({date:-1}); will be run against ALL the shards :(